# p:dialog does not pickup date from p:schedule

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog

My p:schedule is not working properly. When I click on a date, it displays a popup with start date and end date. But it does not pickup the date in the popup. I follow the example on the showcase but yet the date field is empty when the popup appears.

appointment.xhtml

```
 <h:form prependId="false">
  <p:schedule id="schedule"
            value="#{Appointment.eventModel}"
            widgetVar="myschedule"
            timeZone="GMT+2">

    <p:ajax event="dateSelect"
            listener="#{Appointment.onDateSelect}"
            oncomplete="PF('eventDialog').show();" />

    <p:ajax event="eventSelect"
            listener="#{Appointment.onEventSelect}"
            update="eventDetails"
            oncomplete="PF('eventDialog').show();" />
</p:schedule>

<p:dialog widgetVar="eventDialog"
          header="Appointment Details"
          showEffect="clip"
          hideEffect="clip">

    <h:panelGrid id="eventDetails" columns="2">
        <p:outputLabel for="title" value="Titles:" />
        <p:inputText id="title"
                     value="#{Appointment.event.title}"
                     required="true" />

        <p:outputLabel for="from" value="From:" />
        <p:calendar id="from"
                    value="#{Appointment.event.startDate}"
                    timeZone="GMT+2" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" />

        <p:outputLabel for="to" value="To:" />
        <p:calendar id="to"
                    value="#{Appointment.event.endDate}"
                    timeZone="GMT+2" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" />


        <p:commandButton type="reset" value="Reset" />
        <p:commandButton id="addButton" value="Save"
                         actionListener="#{Appointment.addEvent}"
                         oncomplete="PF('myschedule').update();
                                     PF('eventDialog').hide();"/>
    </h:panelGrid>
</p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

Appointment.java

```
public class Appointment implements AppointmentInterface {

    public ScheduleModel getEventModel() {
        eventModel = new DefaultScheduleModel();
        return eventModel;
    }

    public void onDateSelect(SelectEvent selectEvent) {
        event = new DefaultScheduleEvent("", (Date) selectEvent.getObject(), (Date) selectEvent.getObject());
    }

    public void onEventSelect(SelectEvent selectEvent) {
        event = (ScheduleEvent) selectEvent.getObject();
    }

    public void addEvent(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        if (event.getId() == null) {
            eventModel.addEvent(event);
        } else {
            eventModel.updateEvent(event);
        }

        event = new DefaultScheduleEvent();
    }
}
```

Comment: So it works if you don't use a dialog but a plain jsf panel?

Comment: I did not try this. BUt my requirement is do it in a dialog box.

Comment: I'm not saying you should in the end not use a dialog, but if you tag it like this, your are kind of indirectly saying it works without a dialog. And btw, your dialog does not pick up anything, the components inside it do (or don't)

Comment: Narrowing things down to the real cause is what debugging and creating an [mcve] is all about. And as a hint: check the differences beween both ajac tags in the `p:schedule`

Comment: Can you show me how to do it with panel? I can't get your point when you say my dialog does not pickup anything. I follow the example on the showcase and it works there!

Comment: The `p:calendar` should pick up the date, not the `p:dialog`. The dialog is just container. And just try to replace the dialog with a panel (the .show() is not needed then).

Comment: Ok how do I make the calendar pickup the date?

Comment: I hope I don't offend you, but you sound like you have very little basic jsf knowledge. So I'd suggest to start by learning that instead of diving into a little more complex examples. And also by doing the things suggested above.

Comment: No you didn't. You are right! No worries.

Comment: Please compare your code with the showcase. The hint I gave above will become visible then…

Comment: I come to know where the problem is. I miss this part in the ajax event for date select. update="eventdetails".
But yet if i have an event on the calendar, when I click on it , it should display the date in the popup instead of blank fields. It works only when I click on a date where I don't have event. Any idea about this?

Comment: Where's the form? You should have a form inside the dialog, and it should be independent from other forms. Also you have to use `process` and `update` attributes in the command buttons, with this you can control what to send and what to update. (e.g. process="@form")

Comment: Start by dropping the `prependId='false'`. It should only be used in very, very specific situations which normal people like us never encounter